# How to display image using Laravel 5.8?

Tags: php, laravel, image, laravel-5.8

I am trying to display image stored in my local. Those file uploaded are in Storage folder

[image: Storage folder]

I am using the follow code to display the image

```
@foreach($publications as $p)
    <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
        <img class="card-img-top" src="{{URL('public/storage/app/{$p->file_name}')}}" alt="{{$p->file_name}}" />
      <div class="card-body">
        <p class="card-text">{{$p->description}}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
@endforeach
```

But I got:

[image]

what's wrong?

**EDIT 1**

I use `php artisan storage:link`, the console displayed

```
The [public/storage] directory has been linked.
```

But it still not working

Comment: Maybe you forgot link your `storage/app/public` folder to `public` folder. Try run `php artisan storage:link`

Comment: @LeventeOtta not working but the console displayed ``The [public/storage] directory has been linked.``

Comment: How do your `public` folder looks like? (Add a screenshot if possible)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**First** you need to do

```
php artisan storage:link
```

so that your storage folder which the wepapp cannot access usually links with your public
folder so that your app can access the pictures like if they are in the public folder 
but it will store them in the storage folder then you should put smthg like this to display the image

*i think it will be like this*

```
    <img src="/storage/2/{{$p->file_name}}"/>
```

**you could edit the path to the path in your application if this path didnt work**

hope it works with you

**Edit i will share with you an example from my code** 
in migration the users migration

```
$table->string('image');
```

controller

```
$imageName = time().'.'.request()->image->getClientOriginalExtension();
        request()->image->move(public_path('userpicture'), $imageName);
        return User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'image' => $imageName,
            'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
        ]);
```

note that the create method i am using here works only when you put those fildes fillable in the user model so never mind you could use whatever you want in the storing data part but concetrate on this three lines

```
$imageName = time().'.'.request()->image->getClientOriginalExtension();
            request()->image->move(public_path('userpicture'), $imageName);

                'image' => $imageName,
```

as you can see the move function is moving the picture to the public folder and putting it in userpicture folder and then the last line store the image name in the database so that i could access it later on to display the picture

and then i could just simply do this to display the picture

```
<img class="img-responsive img-rounded" src="{{ asset('userpicture/1561335133.jpg') }}" alt="User picture">
```

Comment: I am not storing the file inside public folfer, as you can see in the first image. Should I store in that folder?

Comment: bro the wepapp in laravel doesnot have the prevligies to access folders like storage and thats why we usually link the storage to public because if you want the picture to be accessable you should either put it directly in public or put it in storage then link it to public because public is the folder that the wepapp may access and display its files in your code you missed this point and always remember that css files .js files and pictures should be in public or in storage with link to the public v

Comment: i shared my code with you that i wrote two days earlier and it is working fine

Answer (score 2):

`php artisan storage:link` creates a symlink to `/storage/app/public`

But it looks like your files are in `/storage/app/files` try moving the files to the public folder.

you can use the asset helper to show the file `{{ asset("storage/{$p->file_name}") }}`

Comment: Not working ``<img class="card-img-top" src="{{ asset("storage/{$p->file_name}") }}" alt="{{$p->file_name}}" />``

Comment: if you use ```{{ asset("storage/2/filename.txt") }}```, the file should be located in ```/storage/app/public/2/filename.txt```