# how to display multiple images on laravel view

Tags: php, laravel

i need help displaying multiple images on laravel, so far I can upload and save the images to the path  **public_path().'images/listing/'.$listing->id.'/'.$name;**.

but I not sure how to display each individual image path correctly on my blade file and display the saved images

my ListingController

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Listing;
use App\ListingImage;

class ListingController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $listings = Listing::all();


        return view('listings')->with('listings', $listings);
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        return view ('listings.create');
    }

    /*
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'title'=>'required',
            'price'=>'required',
            'address'=>'required',
            'rooms'=>'required',
            'city'=>'required',
            'state'=>'required',
            'area'=>'required',
            'bathrooms'=>'required',
            'description'=>'required',
            'status'=>'required',
            'type'=>'required',
            'images' => 'required',
            'images.*' => 'mimes:png,jpg,jpeg,gif,svg|max:2048'
        ]);

        $listing = new Listing();
        $listing->title = $request->input('title');
        $listing->price = $request->input('price');
        $listing->address = $request->input('address');
        $listing->rooms = $request->input('rooms');
        $listing->city = $request->input('city');
        $listing->state = $request->input('state');
        $listing->zip_code = $request->input('zip_code');
        $listing->area = $request->input('area');
        $listing->building_age = $request->input('building_age');
        $listing->bedrooms = $request->input('bedrooms');
        $listing->bathrooms = $request->input('bathrooms');
        $listing->description = $request->input('description');
        $listing->status = $request->input('status');
        $listing->type = $request->input('type');
        $listing->save();

        foreach ($request->file('images') as $image) {
            $listingImage = new ListingImage;
            $name = $image->getClientOriginalName();
            $path = public_path().'images/listing/'.$listing->id.'/'.$name;
            $image->move($path);
            $listingImage->listing_id = $listing->id;
            $listingImage->image_path = $path;
            $listingImage->save();
        }
        return redirect()->back()->with('success', 'Listing saved!');
    }
}
```

the listing.blade.php

```
@foreach($listings as $listing)
                <!-- Listing Item -->
                <div class="listing-item">

                    <a href="single-property-page-1.html" class="listing-img-container">

                        <div class="listing-badges">
                        <span>{{ $listing->status }}</span>
                        </div>

                        <div class="listing-img-content">
                            <span class="listing-price">{{$listing->price}} <i>$520 / sq ft</i></span>
                            <span class="like-icon with-tip" data-tip-content="Add to Bookmarks"></span>
                            <span class="compare-button with-tip" data-tip-content="Add to Compare"></span>
                        </div>


                        <div class="listing-carousel">
                            **@foreach($listing->images as $image)
                            <div><img src="{{ asset('$image->image_path') }}" alt=""></div>
                            @endforeach**
                        </div>
                    </a>

                    <div class="listing-content">

                        <div class="listing-title">
                        <h4><a href="#">{{$listing->title}}</a></h4>
                            <a href="" class="listing-address popup-gmaps">
                                <i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i>
                                {{$listing->address}}
                            </a>

                            <a href="single-property-page-1.html" class="details button border">Details</a>
                        </div>

                        <ul class="listing-details">
                            <li>530 sq ft</li>
                            <li>{{$listing->bedrooms}} Bedroom</li>
                            <li>{{$listing->rooms}} Rooms</li>
                            <li>{{$listing->bathrooms}} Bathroom</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>

                </div>
                <!-- Listing Item / End -->
                @endforeach
```

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/56728357/11801683

Comment: @jewishmoses please I need help understanding what to do about the file storage link

Comment: open the terminal in project root folder and run `php artisan storage:link` it will create a symbolic link from public/storage to storage/app/public. Read here https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/filesystem#the-public-disk

Comment: i use the php artisan storage:link but how can this help display the images @jewishmoses

Comment: It's explained here very well.. https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/filesystem#the-public-disk

Comment: @TobyNwude Did it solved your problem?

Comment: @RajeshPaudel i followed your method, the images was saved in the correct directory but it isn't displaying in the view

Comment: @TobyNwude Try once again

Comment: @RajeshPaudel the images isn't displaying, it is being saved as public/images/listing/1/capture.PNG.PNG/php86B4.tmp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can see **public_path()** gives your full path to your public folder from the root filesystem. And often in laravel web application development you don't want the full path from the filesystem while rendering the file. You only want it at the time of moving the file so it can point to proper location from the root filesystem. In laravel you want the path from the public folder so.

Use this as a code.

```
     
    $imageName = time().'.'.$image->getClientOriginalExtension();
    $image->move(public_path('images/listing/'.$listing->id), $imageName);
    $listingImage->listing_id = $listing->id;
    $listingImage->image_path = 'images/listing/'.$listing->id."/".$imageName;
    $listingImage->save();
```

And then on your view use

```
{{ asset($image->image_path) }}
```

Comment: You can also use the [store](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/requests#storing-uploaded-files) method

Comment: the images is not saved properly in the directory
it's been saved as this
**images/listing/1/Capture2.PNG.PNG**

Comment: @TobyNwude are you using php artisan serve? Or it is being served from public?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried echo out `asset('$image->image_path')`?

I guess you have to remove the single quotes here since you want to insert the value of `$image->image_path`.

Comment: I'm not getting a value, I need to display the image stored in the image_path